# How To Remove Background Color Of material-bottom-tabs in react native

Tags: react-native

I use

> @react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs

how do i remove orange background color or make it transparent.

so it feels like floating

[image]

hire my code

```
const MainTabScreen = () => (
<Tab.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Home"
  activeColor="#e9118c"
  inactiveColor="#95a5a6"
  shifting={true}
  sceneAnimationEnabled={true}
  tabBarBadge={true}
  style={{ 
    backgroundColor: 'tomato',
   //backgroundColor: 'transparent',
   //opacity:0.7
  }}
  barStyle={{ 
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    borderRadius:50,
    marginBottom:10,
    marginTop:5,
    paddingHorizontal:12,
    paddingTop:12,
    height:80,
    borderColor:'#fff',
    marginHorizontal:5
  }}
>
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: 'Home',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
        <Icon name="ios-home" color={color} size={26} />
      ),
    }}
  />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use position:'absolute' in the bar style like below, no need to use the styles.

```
     barStyle={{
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 50,
        marginBottom: 10,
        marginTop: 5,
        paddingHorizontal: 12,
        paddingTop: 12,
        height: 80,
        borderColor: '#fff',
        marginHorizontal: 5, 
        position: "absolute",
      }}>
```

Comment: Wouldn't the tab bar overlap other screen content if position is set to `absolute`?